# Transparent text on colored background in CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there possible to show some text in a div/span/etc with colored background AND transparent characters with `CSS`? I attached an image to simply show what I want to do.

my HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="textbox">this text is transparent</div>
</div>
```

my CSS code:

```
#container {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('...path/to/myimage.jpg');
}
#textbox {
    background: #000;
    color: transparent; /* ??? */
}
```

[image: transparent text on image via CSS]

Comment: this has been asked some times, the only easy solution supports only webkit-based browsers by using `-webkit-background-clip:text` and `-webkit-text-fill-color:transparent`, however it's hard to find a cross-browser solution or it may become very complicated.

Comment: I mean in your words there is a cross-browser solution... is there?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Maybe someone knows but I've not known of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SVG,  it needs some extra to tuning: width of svg in order to see all text, set a background pattern same as background.

SVG text do not wrap yet (svg 2.0 should).

the only advantage is that it is supported by Firefox when background-clip:text; does not.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mucoj)**

HTML + SVG inline content:

```
</div>
  <svg height="5em" width="32em">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="textpattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1000" height="1000" >
        <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/nature/9" width="600" height="300"  x="-3em" y="-3em"/>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <text  y="1.2em" x="0.5em" >​this text is transparent</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Associated CSS to demo :

```
text {
  font-size:3em;
  fill:url(#textpattern) ;
}
svg {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  margin:2em 0 0 2em;
}
#container {
  padding:1em;
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/300/nature/9) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This is still some kind of ***workaround***, the text is not really  transparent, it just has the same background to the parent's background, if there are some other elements behind, we can just see the parent's background through the text like in [this Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kvawn). This kind of transparency is fake, not real. However it may suit the OP in some cases.

Comment: is n't it what background-clip does ?

Comment: yes, it's hard to have real text transparency in web. That's why I said it may suit the OP.

Comment: so this kind of technique requires the background position of the text to be in sync with the background position of the parent, here is another issue http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGmwv changing the height of some element before (the `#textbox`), it will push the `svg` down and hence the problem occurs.

Comment: @KingKing I agree with you, that's why i mentionned the tunning to do and the only advantage aside background-clip is that Firefox gets it . the real only way to make transparent text in SVG *(that i know of)* , and see it, is to use a stroke around it , but far too from result desired :) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/tCEiD

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `-webkit-background-clip`.

[CSS-tricks article "Show Image Under Text"](http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/) gives you some good options.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-clip.asp (and as @Josh mentioned, http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/)

Looks like that it's well supported (with the latest browsers at-least)